# Droppable and sortable functions on dynamically created elements not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Stuck with this issue for the past 2 days :-( Trying to create draggable sortable list with dynamically added groups. Was able to create containers, but divs cant be dropped to these containers.. Can somebody point out where I am doing it wrong, I know that it has to be assigned to a variable, even tried that, still now working..
Fiddle is as follows..

http://jsfiddle.net/Sullan/mLHJW/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just repeated the call within the button click.. not sure whether its the right way.. but works out fine...

http://jsfiddle.net/Sullan/mLHJW/1/

Answer (score 5):

if dynmmcally created elements not working try using `on` in jquery version 1.7 . if you are using less than that , like 1.6 , 1.5 or something you can use `live`

example

```
$("p").on("click", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

or

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

insted of

```
$("p").click( function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

`on` ad `live`  wil be added to the dynamically created elements

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

try using this plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery#Download

once you include it just use it like this (example from your code):

```
var test = $('ul.itemsList').livequery(function(){
                    $(this).sortable({
                        connectWith: $('.itemsList, .itemsList li')
                    });
               });
```